# Unable to import lightgbm after install

Tags: macos, lightgbm

My operating system is macOS Sierra, 10.12.5, and I am using Anaconda and python 2.7. After install, and when I try:
import lightgbm as lgb
I got the following message:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2ae3725bef24> in <module>()
----> 1 import lightgbm as lgb

/Users/tenggao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/__init__.py in <module>()
      7 from __future__ import absolute_import
      8 
----> 9 from .basic import Booster, Dataset
     10 from .callback import (early_stopping, print_evaluation, record_evaluation,
     11                        reset_parameter)

/Users/tenggao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in <module>()
     29 
     30 
---> 31 _LIB = _load_lib()
     32 
     33 

/Users/tenggao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in _load_lib()
     24     if len(lib_path) == 0:
     25         raise Exception("cannot find LightGBM library")
---> 26     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
     27     lib.LGBM_GetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
     28     return lib

/Users/tenggao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    438 
    439     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 440         return self._dlltype(name)
    441 
    442 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

/Users/tenggao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    360 
    361         if handle is None:
--> 362             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    363         else:
    364             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/Users/tenggao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libiomp/lib/libiomp5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/tenggao/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered the same issue on my mac, which is fixed by simply installing OpenMP library.

```
brew install libomp
```

[For any doubt please visit the installation page here](https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/)

Answer (score 4):

I had the issue as you before. Actually, LightGBM depends on OpenMP for compiling, which isn't supported by Apple Clang. You should install gcc/g++ by using following command:

```
brew install cmake
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

See more details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Installation-Guide)
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I follow the instruction here:https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_LightGBM_for_Anaconda_on_MacOSX?lang=en
to install lightgbm, and I have read the instruction again, seems like there are some changes compared to last time I did it. So, maybe I will uninstall my gcc and do it over again.

Answer (score 2):

I followed both (https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1369) and the installation guide from the website (https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html#macos)

Since I have gcc version 9.1.0, I used:

> git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM
>   export CXX=g++-9 CC=gcc-9
>   mkdir build ; cd build
>   cmake ..
>   make -j4

in the implementation of my installation, then I ran:

> pip install --no-binary :all: lightgbm

After importing the lightgbm into my jupyter notebook, it gave me the warning of installing the libomp, so I also did:

> brew install libomp

Then the warning went away.