# Lightgbm OSError, Library not loaded

Tags: python, macos, lightgbm

If I simply do:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
```

I'm getting

```
python script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
import lightgbm as lgb
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .basic import Booster, Dataset
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 31, in <module>
_LIB = _load_lib()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 26, in _load_lib
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgomp.1.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
Reason: image not found
```

I seem to have everything installed correct:

```
python -m pip install lightgbm
Requirement already satisfied: lightgbm in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from lightgbm)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from lightgbm)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from lightgbm)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from lightgbm)
```

I do have a 6 folder in my GCC folder.  Should I need to install another version of GCC for this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find a similar problem here [LightGBM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506921/unable-to-import-lightgbm-after-install)
The answer and comment may help you.

Build LightGBM in Mac:

```bash
brew install cmake  
brew install gcc --without-multilib  
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM  
mkdir build ; cd build  
cmake ..   
make -j
```

Then install:

```bash
cd ../python-packages  
sudo python setup.py install --precompile
```

As stated by @ecodan, you might need to force Mac to use GCC and G++ instead of the default compiler. So instead of building with `cmake ..`, try:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/gcc-6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/g++-6 ..
```

ajusting the versions to match yours.

Comment: FWIW, my HighSierra Mac prefers AppleCLang over GCC, so I had to force the path as such:  cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/gcc-6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0/bin/g++-6 ..

Comment: can I do pip install lightgbm? I did that I got the same error message that the library doesn't load.

Comment: The folder name is python-package (without the s) (in LightGBM version 2.1.2)

Comment: `--without-multilib` does not exist anymore

Comment: just remove `--without-multilib` and it will work

Comment: also for `cmake` , check the version you have by doing `ls /usr/local/Cellar/gcc` and use the version you have instead of the one shown in the post

Answer (score 87):

All the above answers didn't work for me.
On Mac, if I installed the libomp using brew fixed the problem: Refer: [link](https://medium.com/@naramsciot/installing-lightgbm-in-macos-mojave-issue-sorted-4f2b81d27a8f)

```
brew install libomp
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. The above stuff didn't work!

Comment: This should be the updated answer. I didn't need any of the steps stated in the accepted answer.

Comment: Works for me as well. simple solution.

Comment: I'm running python in a virtual environment (venv) and this answer solved the OSError.

Comment: Worked for me too on macOS 11.6.5; thanks!

Comment: It still does not work for me even though I have `libomp 14.0.6 is already installed and up-to-date.`

Comment: works for me on macOS 12.2.1, thanks

Comment: @Pedram Did you find a solution? It is also still not working for me...

Answer (score 17):

I had the same exact problem on M1 MAC. I have tried to import it through Jupiter notebook. This command solved the problem:

```
conda install lightgbm
```

Answer (score 4):

On MAC you need to install open-mpi:

```
brew install open-mpi
```

Answer (score 2):

Same error, different source: seems like I had the **gcc 8** version installed, and it needs gcc 7.

It worked by switching it back to last gcc 7 version:

```
brew switch gcc 7.3.0_1
```

Comment: hi I met exactly the same problem and use gcc8. I'd like to try out your suggestion. However, `brew switch gcc 7.3.0_1` does not work as it doesn't have this version installed. Do you know how to install this version?

Comment: How to `install gcc 7` while keep `gcc 8`

Answer (score 1):

For users with macports, replace the beginning of the brew solution with:

1. `port install gcc7 cmake`
2. `export CXX=g++-mp-7 CC=gcc-mp-7`

Comment: Yep, had the same problem. Check out https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Installation-Guide.rst#macos

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS High Sierra with MacPorts installed, I did the following:

1. Install `clang-5.0` using MacPorts
2. Inside the `/build` directory, run
   `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-mp-5.0 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-mp-5.0 ..`
3. To build the python package, go to `/python_package` directory and modify the `setup.py` script.
   You need to modify the function `compile_cpp()` at the very end that checks the case for other OS (including Mac). Before the `silent_call(...)`, add the following two lines:

   `cmake_cmd.append("-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-mp-5.0")
   cmake_cmd.append("-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-mp-5.0")`
4. Run `sudo python setup.py install`. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I used this command generated from PyCharm and it worked for me.

**conda install -p { < =replace with USER_HOME_DIR>}/anaconda3 lightgbm -y**

Note : i tried Brew and pip install but they didn't work for me as Azure ML studio already downloaded other versions of LightGBM that were causing conflict in upgrading to correct packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm
```