# lightgbm version incompatible

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, lightgbm

I installed the latest version of `lightGBM`(`lgb.__version__ == '2.2.1'`) which is supported by `gcc8`, but now I have a model already built with `lightgbm==2.0.2` which is supported by `gcc7`.

I need to conform with the previous version, which means I have to downgrade current version of `lightgbm`, using `pip install lightgbm==2.0.2`, however when I import it, I met `Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgomp.1.dylib`.

I have checked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1369) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937698/lightgbm-oserror-library-not-loaded), the problem is I must use `lightgbm` of previous version.

I assume the problem is caused by `gcc` version, so is there a way I can install `gcc 7`?(by the way I tried create a `virtualenv` on my computer so that I can have both version of `lightgbm`, also can I install `gcc 7` under the virtual environment and keep `gcc 8` on my computer as well?)

Thanks soooo much!

Comment: So I don't entirely know where your problem is but I would recommend uninstall both version completely if possible and reinstalling them in virtual environments so as to prevent future version issues. It is of course possible to keep one global and have another in just a virtual environment but it isn't recommended.

Comment: How can I install `gcc 7`? I used `brew install gcc`, it will install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

So to start off with, it looks like your problem has more to do with gcc than with your python module. While it is a best practice to use virtual environments for each project, that will only effect the `lightgbm` module and **not** your gcc version.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, I would recommend taking a look at the following:

[Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula#4158763)

Their solution is with postgresql but it should translate to most other programs installed with Homebrew.

The only other option I can think of would be to just use the newest versions of `lightgbm` and gcc but that doesn't appear to be possible for your project.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found out this works for me `cp -r /usr/local/opt/gcc@7/lib/gcc/7 /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/`